# Is there a compression algorithm for an array of unique keys that quickly lets me add a key, remove a key, or check for the existence of a key?

Tags: algorithm, hash, compression

I'm thinking about developing a storage-efficient voting system. Users of my app should be able to upvote or downvote a post, undo their vote, vote again, etc. but may never register multiple votes for a single post (just like StackOverflow).

The obvious way for me to store this data would be something like this.. (I'm using names below, but assume these are unique IDs)

```
{
  postId: 123,
  upvotedBy: ["bob", "sally", "mark"],
  downvotedBy: ["susan", "ryan"],
  score: 1
}
```

In the event a post goes viral, these arrays could become quite large and might even exceed the storage limit for a single database record. This got me thinking, **maybe there is a mathematical trick whereby I can avoid storing these arrays**. My only requirements are

1. quickly check if user X has registered a vote
2. allow user X to register a vote (if he hasn't already)
3. allow user X to deregister his vote (if has registered one)

### Bad Solution

Suppose every user's id is a prime number. For example

```
bob: 2
sally: 3
mark: 5
susan: 7
ryan: 11
```

For each post, I can initialize `upvotedBy` and `downvotedBy` to 1

```
{
  postId: 123,
  upvotedBy: 1,
  downvotedBy: 1,
  score: 0
}
```

When a user upvotes a post, I simply set `upvotedBy := upvotedBy * userId` (and the same for when he downvotes a post). Now I can quickly check if a user has already voted for a post, and I can register and deregister votes quickly. My example above would now look like

```
{
  postId: 123,
  upvotedBy: 30,
  downvotedBy: 77,
  score: 1
}
```

Of course, this becomes highly storage inefficient once I start multiplying thousands of prime numbers together.

### Question

Does a storage and processing efficient compression algorithm that achieves these requirements exist?

Comment: The obvious way is to have a table represent a many-to-many relation: posts and users.

Comment: The voting information is already being compressed, simply by keeping lists of the voters (provided that the user ID is efficiently encoded). To understand this, let's imagine that there 1 million users, and user IDs are represented by 20-bit numbers. The uncompressed voting information is 1 million bits, 1 bit per user. If 1000 users vote, then the compressed voting information is a list of 1000 20-bit numbers. That's `1000*20 = 20000` bits, which is a whopping 50-to-1 compression ratio compared to the raw million bits.

Comment: @greybeard but I'm interested in solving the puzzle just for the sake of solving the puzzle. (Also, I'm using a nosql database that charges for reads and writes, so there's a practical reason to avoid big junction tables.)

Comment: In general, there's no clever algorithm that will let you compress the *average* case by more than 0%; rather, compression algorithms always work by exploiting redundancy in typical real data (so that real data is compressed by more than 0% but random data ends up bloated). This is because there are 2^N distinct possible texts of length N, so no compression algorithm can compress them all into a shorter length.

Comment: That said, you may get some use from a Bloom filter, which will let you quickly check if a user has *probably* voted. But there's always the risk of false positives, and you need to decide how to handle that risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can check for the existence of a key, then your data structure is equivalent to storing all the keys.

There is a lower bound on how much space it takes to do that, and there are [succinct data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succinct_data_structure) that get pretty close to that lower bound in all cases.  They're pretty complicated though, and are not going to be practical for your use case.

If you insist, you can use the [Roaring Bitmaps](https://roaringbitmap.org/) library.

But why do you really want to compress this data in the first place?  If it's to reduce network traffic or allow for efficient operation, then the solution is to store just the counts (or nothing, because normalization) with the post and move the votes themselves into a separate table, as @greybeard suggests in comments.

Answer (score 2):

> - quickly check if user X has registered a vote
> - allow user X to register a vote (if he hasn't already)
> - allow user X to deregister his vote (if has registered one)

To satisfy this, you can have each *user* store a set of posts they've upvoted.  The reasons for doing that is that there's a lower limit on how many posts a user might reasonably upvote (indeed, if they're upvoted an absurd number, it'd probably be best to prevent them from upvoting more), whereas a popular post could have many millions of upvotes.  The posts then need only store a total number of upvotes - very space efficient.

It would be ideal - from a memory-usage perspective whilst having O(1) performance - to use use an open addressing aka closed hashing hash table with a prime number of buckets (less collision prone, allowing reasonable use of higher load factors, which means less wasted memory).  Post id numbers can be pretty much any numbers then, even incrementing integers (with gaps if posts are deleted).